# Is it better to sprint or walk while cloaked?

Tags: crysis

Having recently bought the original Crysis on the PC, I found cloaking to be extremely useful for sneaking around. However, I also noticed that my nanosuit's energy decreases much more rapidly when I'm sprinting than when I'm walking. So is it better to walk or run while cloaked (i.e. which one lets you go further from a full energy suit)?

Comment: Can't you just try it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you answered your own question in the process of asking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walking gives the maximum distance availabe while cloaked in a long time, running gives a moderate distance while cloaked with the normal speed at a moderate time, Sprinting gives the shortest distance at high speed at a short time.
So depends on your situation and what you want to do and choose.
I Finished Crysis 2, there sprinting takes away much more energy, even while not cloaked
And I finished Crysis 3, where Sprinting takes no energy without cloaking, but while cloaking, I noticed sprinting taking slightly lesser energy than it's prequel.